# reset id whenever a row deleted in django

Tags: django, django-models

i wanted to start id from 1 .
whenever a row deleted it skips that number and jump to next number.
[image]

like in this image it skips number from 1-6 and 8.

i want to set it as 1,2,3

this is my models.py

```
class dish(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)      
dish_id = models.AutoField
dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
dish_category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
dish_size = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
dish_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
dish_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
# dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/", default=None, blank=True, null=True) #here added images as a foldername to upload to.
dish_date = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.dish_name
```

this is views.py

```
def delete(request, id):
dishs = dish.objects.get(id=id)
dishs.delete()
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('check'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to reset id whenever a row deleted in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763241/how-to-reset-id-whenever-a-row-deleted-in-django)