# how to reset id whenever a row deleted in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I wanted to start id from `1` whenever a row is deleted it skips that number and jumps to the following number.

[image]

like in this image it skips numbers from `1-6` and `8`.

I want to set it as `1,2,3`.

Here is my `models.py` module

```py
class dish(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)      
    dish_id = models.AutoField
    dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_size = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dish_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    # dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/", default=None, blank=True, null=True) #here added images as a foldername to upload to.
    dish_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dish_name
```

Here is `views.py` module:

```py
def delete(request, id):
    dishs = dish.objects.get(id=id)
    dishs.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('check'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an object does not change any property of the remaining objects.  You need to do that manually.  First thing you need to do is to change the `dish_id` field:

```py
# Change this:
# dish_id = models.AutoField
# to this:
dish_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then in your views:

```py
def delete(request, id):
    dishs = dish.objects.get(id=id)
    dishs.delete()

    all_dishes = dish.objects.all()
    for i, dish in enumerate(all_dishes):
        dish.dish_id = i + 1
        dish.save()
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('check'))
```

Separately, you really should write your classes in Pascal case, capitalizing the first letter of the class:

```py
class Dish(models.Model):
```

And finally, `Dish` does not need an id field; that is created automatically, but you can leave that as is, it is not causing any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve those things using an overriding save() method like this

```
class dish(models.Model):
    id =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)      
    dish_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique = True)
    dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_size = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dish_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/", default=None, blank=True, null=True) #here added images as a foldername to upload to.
    dish_date = models.DateField()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dish_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        count_obj = dish.objects.all().count()+1
        self.dish_id = count_obj
        super(dish, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```